# Can this ODE be solved analytically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wrote a question about numerically computing a ODE in the Numerical Computation forum, and when I had solved the problem I started thinking "What if it could also be solved analytically?". How can find this out? Maybe for some subgroup of ODEs we can identify some qualifiers for it to be analytically solvable? In either case, here is the link to the ODE and the post I made: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33421/1-d-boundary-value-problem-how-implement-mixed-boundary-conditions-using-a-fd-m

Now, I have some knowledge of how to solve difficult ODEs analytically with separation of variables and Greens functions and so on. Is it possible for this case? If so, how do I go about calculating this exact solution?

Best regards,

Comment: On the face of it, it looks solvable, because it's second-order linear with constant coefficients. In fact, there's no $T$ term, only $T'$ and $T''.$ That simplifies matters a bit. By the way, instead of linking to your other post, you should type the equation up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is of the first order in terms of $\dfrac{dT}{dz}$, linear with constant coefficients. The solution of the homogeneous equation is a positive exponential, and so is the step response. The regime solution to a sinusoidal RHS is also a sinusoid, which you easily compute using the complex representation.

The composite signal can be obtained by concatenating three piecewise solutions.

The function $T$ is obtained as the antiderivative of $\dfrac{dT}{dz}$ (or you can solve the second order equation directly).

Answer (score 1):

The given equation is an inhomogeneous constant-coefficient linear equation of second order. In particular, one can find two linearly independent exponential solutions of the homogeneous equation easily, and then one can use the method of [variation of parameters](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VariationofParameters.html) to solve the inhomogeneous equation.